# Convert gml fragment with srs attribute to wkt with geotools

Tags: geotools, wkt, gml-geographic-markup-lan

I have the following gml fragment:

```xml
      <gml:LineString srsName="EPSG:25832"><gml:coordinates>663957.75944074022118,5103981.64908889029175 663955.915655555087142,5103991.151674075052142</gml:coordinates></gml:LineString>
```

I would like to convert it to a wkt string with the EPSG:4326 srs.

Comment: what have your tried so far? what is not working?

Comment: See my answer, it works but has too many assumptions...

Answer (score 0):

I found a hacky solution, the main isue, is that the input is just a gml fragment and not a valid document. So it is not possible to use xpath to extract the srsName attribute, because the namespaces are not bound.
I searched with a regex for the srsName attribute and transformed the geometry.

```java
try {                                                                                
    String gml = "<gml:LineString srsName=\"EPSG:25832\"><gml:coordinates>663957.75944074022118,5103981.64908889029175 663955.915655555087142,5103991.151674075052142</gml:coordinates></gml:LineString>";                                              
    Geometry geometry = gmlReader.read(gml, geometryFactory);                        
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("srsName=\\\"([^\"]*)\\\"");                         
    Matcher m = p.matcher(gml);                                                      
    if (m.find()) {                                                                  
        String srs = m.group(1);                                                     
        CoordinateReferenceSystem crsSource = CRS.decode(srs);                       
        GeographicCRS crsTarget =                                                    
                org.geotools.referencing.crs.DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84;             
        MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(crsSource, crsTarget, false);
        geometry = JTS.transform(geometry, transform);                               
    }                                                                                 
    String wktString = wktWriter.write(geometry);                                         
} catch (Exception e) {                                                              
    throw new RuntimeException(e);                                                   
}
```

Ugly as ****, is there a cleaner way?